# Load fonts directly to Xcode from finder folder (mac OS)

Tags: xcode, macos, fonts

I'am creating a Mac OS application in which user will choose a font to display a text. All fonts will be in an application folder in finder. I need a code (swift or objective-c) to load it directly (without installing) to Xcode so user feel free to add any font to the folder to use.

Comment: install new font in xcode